# how to create a validation on detailview class?

Tags: python, django

I want to keep Post Details visible only for the author of the post.

This is my View class

```
class PostDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
```

This is my form class

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

This is my Model class

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I check(within my view) if the current user is the author of the post?

Answer (score 2):

you will have to use the `UserPassesTestMixin` to check if the user is who is supposed to be.

```
class PostDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.id == self.get_object().author_id
```

`test_func` should be a function that returns True if the logged in user is allowed to see the content

Comment: Good answer, but `self.request.user == self.get_object().author` is needed as `self.object` won't be defined at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own permission mixin. A simple example:

```
# mixins.py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from your_app.models import Post


class PostCreatorRequiredMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['pk'])  # Assuming your url uses the the parameter name `pk` which is used by DetailView by default.
        if post.author != request.user:
            return redirect('user_is_not_the_post_owner.html')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And then in your `views.py` use it to check the permission:

```
from mixins import PostCreatorRequiredMixin

class PostDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, PostCreatorRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
```

Writing a mixin will help to avoid code repetition when you have to check the same permission in multiple views.